# Pie Menu Operator with several properties

Tags: python, add-on, pie-menu

Is it possible to specify several operator properties for a Pie Menu operator?

I have an operator that has two properties, axis and type:

`bpy.ops.object.myscript.align(axis="X", type="TO_LAST")`

I can add it to a pie like this:

`pie.operator("myscript.align", text="Align X").axis="X"`

But can I specify the type at the same time as the axis? Or do I have to create another operator just for that?

Comment: From where do you got that info how to create your own Pie-Menu? I would like to create my own PieMenu too, can you provide me some more Infos ?

Comment: Off topic, but you can watch this tutorial to begin with: https://vimeo.com/103321600
There is a Pie Menu template script in blender that you can create from the Text Editor.

Comment: Thanx much appreciated

Comment: So I went with creating a new operator for each combination of properties that I need, but then I lose the Redo Last menu... I can't find a proper a simple way to do what I want.